# Can docker use http request to pull images from private registry?

Tags: docker, http, containers, docker-registry, docker-registry-mirror

I want to capture `http` requests when I pull images from private registry. But it doesn't work. I use `wireshark` and only capture tcp requests.

I use

```
sudo docker run -d  -v /opt/registry/data:/var/lib/registry -p 5000:5000  --name myregistry registry:latest
```

to start my private registry. And add

```
{
   "insecure-registries": [
      "127.0.0.1:5000"
    ]
}
```

in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Use

```
sudo docker tag ubuntu:latest 127.0.0.1:5000/ubuntu:latest
```

and

```
sudo docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/ubuntu:latest
```

to push images to private registry.

And use

```
sudo docker pull 127.0.0.1:5000/ubuntu:latest
```

to pull images from private registry.

But when I add a http url:http://f1361db2.m.daocloud.io in the `registry-mirrors`. I can capture `http` requests when I pull images.

Is this because I deploy the private registry in a wrong way？ Or it doesn't support http protocol in private registry?

Best regards.

Thanks!

Comment: Check how to use wireshark for loopback address...!!  The issue is not with the private registry but in the way wireshark is being used.